# Constructing a URL with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I have a web service that I am trying to get some data from. The final URL should look something like this:

http://server.com/services/v2/item/3?....ect

The value 3 in the above URL is dynamic and I need to change it base on a user action. I have all that part down and for the URL I just put the parameters into an `NSDictionary` like all my otherwise services.

The only difference is this web service doesn't use a key for the value, like the other web services do. So I just put the value into NSDictionary without the key.

After making the request the final URL looks like this:

http://server.com/services/v2/item/?3.....ect

The base URL I am using: http://server.com/services/v2/item/

I just need a value in front of it with the question mark after the value, not before.

Comment: why don't you use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]` and construct the URL?

Comment: Not sure how that would help? If I add a string into the dictionary with that I need the parameter to look like: "3?" at the end of the base URL - when AFNetworking makes the request it changes the URL to "?3" at the end of the base URL. Which is not what I am after. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/services/v2/item/%d?",myValue] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Instead of passing a `NSDictionary` to `parameters`, pass `nil`. Then construct the URL with parameters with `stringWithFormat`, and pass it to `GET`

Comment: Thanks. However the app uses 140 different web services. So I have made one class to handle all of those services and I use NSDictionaries. I don't really want to change everything from NSDictionary to NSString. However your answer has given me an idea so I will do some testing now. Thanks

Comment: This helped me solve my issue. I modified the URL just before the request was made, using NSString stringWithFormat - as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually base URL is set to you api endpoint root, so in your case it should be http://server.com/services/v2.

Also it's ok to pass parameters (the ID of item in your case) via url string and mix it with `parameters` dictionary.

The method to fetch an item may look like this

```
...
// Set a base URL to your session/operations manager
self.sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://server.com/services/v2"]];
...


- (NSURLDataTask *)fetchItemWithID:(NSString *)ID parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:... failure:...
{
    NSString *urlPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"item/%@", ID);

    return [self.sessionManager GET:urlPathString parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
}
```